# ASP.NET MVC 2+ and PRG pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I just learned about the existence of the PRG pattern, and I'm wondering if ASP.NET MVC 2 or above implements it out of the box.  If not, are there any relevant examples or tutorials?  I've seen some for MVC 1, but I'm not sure if they're still relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it has support for it. But classic asp.net does have the support too. It's just about redirecting the page after post. In MVC, in your Create/Update/Delete action you implement the PRG by returning `RedirectToAction` instead of `View`.

See, for example, https://blog.iannelson.uk/an-mvc-gotcha-and-the-prg-pattern/ for detailed explanation.